# Как оптимизировать MySQL-таблицу, в которой хранится множество названий фильмов?

Tags: mysql, база-данных, оптимизация, индексы

Здравствуйте. Есть примерно такая таблица с фильмами `films`:

```
+-----+---------------+----------+
| id  | premiere_date | duration |
+-----+---------------+----------+
| 432 | 2015-10-11    | 68       |
| 433 | 2015-10-28    | 125      |
+-----+---------------+----------+
```

Поле `id` в ней инкрементное и является primary key. Также есть таблица с названиями фильмов `films_titles`:

```
+---------+----------------+------------+------------------------------------------+
| film_id | title_language | title_type | title                                    |
+---------+----------------+------------+------------------------------------------+
| 432     | en             | 1          | Intouchables                             |
| 432     | ru             | 2          | 1+1                                      |
| 432     | ru             | 3          | Неприкасаемые                            |
| 433     | en             | 1          | The Hunger Games                         |
| 433     | ru             | 2          | Голодные игры                            |
| 433     | de             | 2          | Die Tribute von Panem – The Hunger Games |
+---------+----------------+------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Поле `title_type` - тип названия фильма. Например, `1` - язык оригинала (может быть только одно для фильма), `2` - официальные названия на других языках (может быть только одно для каждого языка), `3` - неофициальные названия.

Собственно, главный вопрос: как бы вы улучшили эти таблицы?

Сейчас все таблицы у меня в InnoDB, через foreign key связал поле `film_id` с полем `id`. Может, на какие-то поля можно индексы повесить? Я читал про них, но никак не могу понять реальных кейсов использования. Также можно как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы нельзя было добавить два названия с одинаковым `film_id`, `title_language` и `title_type`? Чтобы, например, случайно не добавили два официальных английских названия фильма, которое по логике должно быть всего одно.

**UPD.** Таблица `films` будет иметь чуть более 30.000 записей, а `film_titles` - примерно в 3 раза больше.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Может вынести оригинальное название в таблицу самих фильмов. Наверняка в каком нибудь списке светится только оно, доставать будет проще. А уже дополнительные названия как сейчас. А подобное ограничение уникальности можно проверять только триггерами

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно и повесть, но зачем? :)  Индексы нужно строить исходя из того, какие запросы идут и какие из них нужно ускорить (а какие -- пока нет).  Don't fix what ain't brocken :)

Что касается ограничения на `film_id`, `title_language`, `title_type`, то нужно добавить UNIQUE индекс на эти три поля.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX films_titles_uniq
    ON films_titles (film_id, title_language, title_type);
```

Comment: Я так понимаю, в таком случае я не смогу добавить более одного неофициального названия фильма на одном языке. Просто когда фильм официально не выходит в стране, его переводят фандабберы или фансабберы, которые сами решают, как перевести его название. Реальные примеры не лезут в голову, но, думаю, вы поняли. В таком случае хорошо было бы добавить все популярные варианты перевода в базу.

Comment: Да.  Если нужно такое, то в PostgreSQL это можно сделать с помощью частичных индексов (partial index), а в MySQL -- увы.

Как вариант -- разбить таблицу с именами на две -- с множественными названиями (неофициальные) и с уникальными (оригинальное).  На самом деле даже официальных переводных может быть несколько (бывало такое в 90-е).